# how to display or append json data from js to html

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

how can we display JSON data from js to html

here is the code i have tried

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url:'load_categories.php',
    type:'get',
    data:{'from':loaded,'to':loadmore},
    success: function (res) {
        var categories = $.parseJSON(res);
      var i=0;
      for (var x in categories){
          alert(categories.date_+i);
           $('#categories').append('<div>'+(categories.date_+i+'</div>'); //not displaying on html
          i++;
      }
        $('#loadmore').attr('num_loaded',(loaded+10));
    }
});
</script>

<div id="categories"></div>

<?php
//load_categories.php
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM impressions LIMIT $from,$to");
//echo "SELECT * FROM impressions LIMIT $from,$to";
$arr = array();
$i= 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    $arr['rec_id_'.$i] = $row['rec_id'];
    $arr['date_'.$i]   = $row['date'];
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

where im doing wrong...

i think something wrong with this **categories.date_+i**, how can we add 0,1,2,...

Comment: what the `alert(categories.date_+i);` tells

Comment: You have a stray `(`: `$('#categories').append('<div>'+(categories.date_+i+'</div>');`

Comment: Check my answer , I've update it , you can use same fields name's from database in javascript json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed your code please five it a try

The correct Code :

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url:'load_categories.php',
    type:'get',
    data:{'from':loaded,'to':loadmore},
    success: function (res) {
        var categories = $.parseJSON(res);

    for(var i=0;i< categories.length;i++)
     { 

         var row = categories[i];

          alert(row.date);
         $('#categories').append('<div>'+row.date+'</div>'); //not displaying on html

      }
        $('#loadmore').attr('num_loaded',(loaded+10));
    }
});
</script>

<div id="categories"></div>

<?php
//load_categories.php
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM impressions LIMIT $from,$to");
//echo "SELECT * FROM impressions LIMIT $from,$to";
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    $arr[] = row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```